# Speed up the crawling process

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on ES 6.5.x and storm crawler 1.10. How can I speed up the crawler to fetch the records.When i check the metrics on its shows an average of 0.4 pages per second. Is there anything do I need to change in the below crawler config. 
[image]

**Crawler-Conf:**

```
config: 
  topology.workers: 2
  topology.message.timeout.secs: 300
  topology.max.spout.pending: 100
  topology.debug: false
  fetcher.server.delay: .25
  fetcher.threads.number: 200
  fetcher.threads.per.queue: 5

  worker.heap.memory.mb: 2048

  topology.kryo.register:
    - com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Metadata

  http.content.limit: -1
  fetchInterval.default: 1440
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120
  fetchInterval.error: -1
  topology.metrics.consumer.register:
     - class: "org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer"
       parallelism.hint: 1
```

Comment: what about your es config? how many sites are you crawling? do they specify a delay in their robots.txt? how many spout instances and ES shards? etc...
BTW I don't think the value for server delay is valid: should be 0.25

Comment: I am using default es-conf and there is no specific crawl delay in robots.txt. Here is the es-conf [link](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml)

Comment: and how many different sites?

Comment: I am crawling one site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are crawling a single site then you don't need 2 workers or more than one ES shard and spout! all the URLs would be directed to a single shard anyway!

You are using 5 threads per queue but only retrieving 2 URLs per bucket from ES (*es.status.max.urls.per.bucket: 2*) and forcing 2 secs between calls to ES (*spout.min.delay.queries: 2000*) so on average the spout can't produce more than 1 URL per second. Also *refresh_interval* in *ES_IndexInit.sh* impacts how quickly changes are visible in the index and therefore how likely you are to get fresh URLs from the request.

Simply change  *es.status.max.urls.per.bucket* to a larger value e.g. 10 and drop *spout.min.delay.queries*  to the same value as  *refresh_interval* in *ES_IndexInit.sh* e.g. 1 sec. This will get you a lot more URLs.